# Add a script to all SharePoint lists?

Tags: javascript, custom-list, master-page

Recently I've added a script for one of my Custom Lists in SharePoint Enterprise 2013 which will make **Sticky Headers**.
It was very use full and now all of my users asked for the same capability in theirs custom lists.
I ran into that how can I add the Script which is a **Js** script to the **Master Page** so it will apply to all **Custom Lists**? This will help to save the time to add **Script Editor** Web Part?

Comment: apply the sticky headers to custom list or all the lists?

Comment: All the Custom lists in a SharePoint Site Collection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User Custom Actions (ScriptLinks) can apply one JavaScript file to your whole Site Collection or one Web (site)

I used it in the recent New Library View which doesn't have a MasterPage or JSLinks and wrote a short note on my learning for the Yammer group: SP FrameWork ►Client-Side◄

https://www.yammer.com/itpronetwork/#/notes/2872092

[ok, I just checked and you first need to subscribe to the group to read  it]

Here are the relevant parts:

**CustomActions (aka ScriptLinks)**

It looks like it is all going to be about (User) Custom Actions, which go back to 2010 !
'User' in the name is misleading, it is because the same underlying technology was/is used for adding Actions to the Ribbon and ListMenu. When applied to the Site or Web they are location='ScriptLink'

https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/en-en/library/office/hh185004(v=office.14).aspx

**Inject  tags**

Basically you inject SCRIPT tags in the HEAD of the page (you can only specify the src=...)

There are 2 execution Scopes:

Site actions are added to every page in the Site Collection (including _layouts pages, which we could NOT do with MasterPages!)

Web actions are only injected in the current Web (and not its subsites!)

**no CSS injection**

I have not seen a way of injecting CSS references, so that means applying CSS with you own injecting code.
Which is no problem because these script are executed early on in the page-load.
(even before msajaxbundle.js, which is weird, because that means you can not use RegisterNamespace)
And by applying Webpack your CSS files will end up in a JS file anway:
https://www.bensmithett.com/smarter-css-builds-with-webpack/

**Tools to add CustomActions**

http://johnliu.net/blog/2015/12/the-safest-future-proof-way-to-brand-your-sharepoint-and-sharepoint-online

John gives good code samples and claims the easiest way to add CustomActions, 
but you have to manually add his ASPX page to every SiteCollection.

If you are on Chrome you might find this Extension easier to use:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-sp-editor/ecblfcmjnbbgaojblcpmjoamegpbodhd/related?hl=en

Comment: Thanks! actually I am very close to success only one more question: were should I add the script in Microsoft site? I have a script link and I know the reference, but were should I add the scripts mentioned in this link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/nl-nl/en-en/library/office/hh185004(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: That is the manual way of attaching; use the Chrome extension I mentioned, or Johns ASPX page you add to your site